# How to have a page/view have a different session duration in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, session, django-sessions

I have a django project for which I must set the `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` setting to 15 minutes, and I can not change that.

In this project there also is a JS editor on a page: users can use the editor to make modification to something, and then hit the "save" button to save the result. The page is handled by a view.

The editing can be time-consuming, so often happens that when the user clicks save, his session is already ended.

How can I make that page and only that page have an unlimited session duration?
Will a `<script>` making like a request each 5 min refresh the session successfully and keep it alive?

Comment: _a `<script>` making like a request each 5 min refresh the session successfully and keep it alive_ Yeah, that's probably the cleanest way.  Do an ajax GET on the current page every 5 minutes.

Comment: Or even just a HEAD request, since you're not going to actually display the fetched content.